# flutter simple calculation Function error

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, calculation

When i call the function one time it run perfectly but if i call it again it will show different value and read the different else block please check the code i am attaching the whole class and driver code and output of the following function
i think there is error in if else condition block i dont undestand why it is giving different values on calling the function 2nd time if i run it again third time it will give correct output

```
enum ComponentCondition { missing, damaged, good }
class ComponentModel {
  String name;
  ComponentCondition condition;

  double rate;

  double componentPercent;
  double kerbWeight;
  double componentPrice;

  int lifespan;
  int age;
  ComponentModel(
      {this.name,
      @required this.rate,
      @required this.lifespan,
      @required this.kerbWeight,
      @required this.componentPercent,
      @required this.age});

  int calculatePrice() {
    double weight = (componentPercent * kerbWeight) / 100;
    age = DateTime.now().year - age;
    double scrapValue = weight * rate;
    int i = lifespan ~/ 3;

    if ((condition == ComponentCondition.good ||
            condition == ComponentCondition.damaged) &&
        i == 0) {
      componentPrice = scrapValue;
    } else if (condition == ComponentCondition.good && age < lifespan) {
      if (age >= 0 && age <= i) {
        print('bestconditionPrice');
        componentPrice = scrapValue * 3;
      } else if (age > i && age <= i * 2) {
        componentPrice = scrapValue * 2;
      } else if (age > i * 2 && age < lifespan) {
        componentPrice = scrapValue * 1.5;
      }
    } else if ((age >= lifespan) || condition == ComponentCondition.damaged) {
      componentPrice = scrapValue;
      print('why??????');
    } else
      componentPrice = 0;

    return componentPrice.toInt();
  }

  void updateCondition(ComponentCondition partCondition) {
    condition = partCondition;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  ComponentModel engine = ComponentModel(
      componentPercent: 18, kerbWeight: 695, rate: 17, lifespan: 13, age: 2021);
  engine.updateCondition(ComponentCondition.good);
  int price = engine.calculatePrice();
  int price2 = engine.calculatePrice();
  print(' price1 :$price');
  print("price2 : $price2");
 
}
```

[image: this is the output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a very well asked question, you presented a perfectly reproducable example, so congrats.

As for your question, I'm not entirely sure what you *want* to happen, but I will show you what to change, so *your compiler* will tell you where you go wrong:

- Use the latest version of Flutter. It supports null-safety.
- Use the `final` keyword a lot more. Every variable, that you do not expect to change, make them `final`. That way, when you *do* change them by accident, your compiler will throw an error and you will immediately notice.
- Initialize all data. Null-safety will help you here because you will again get compile errors when you forget.
- Do not keep instance data, just because you can. If something *can* be a local variable, *make* it a local variable.
- Do keep methods short and concise, so do not go into endless if/then chains when you can simply return and be done with it.

So after a few best practice changes, your code looks like this:

```
enum ComponentCondition { missing, damaged, good }

class ComponentModel {
  String? name;
  ComponentCondition condition = ComponentCondition.good;

  final double rate;
  final double componentPercent;
  final double kerbWeight;
  final int lifespan;
  final int age;
  
  ComponentModel(
      {this.name,
      required this.rate,
      required this.lifespan,
      required this.kerbWeight,
      required this.componentPercent,
      required this.age });

  int calculatePrice() {
    final weight = (componentPercent * kerbWeight) / 100;
    final double scrapValue = weight * rate;
    final i = lifespan ~/ 3;
    
    age = DateTime.now().year - age;

    if ((condition == ComponentCondition.good || condition == ComponentCondition.damaged) && i == 0) {
      return scrapValue.toInt();
    }
    
    if (condition == ComponentCondition.good && age < lifespan) {
      if (age >= 0 && age <= i) {
        print('bestconditionPrice');
        return (scrapValue * 3).toInt();
      } 
      
      if (age > i && age <= i * 2) {
        return (scrapValue * 2).toInt();
      } 
      
      if (age > i * 2 && age < lifespan) {
        return (scrapValue * 1.5).toInt();
      }
    } 
    
    if ((age >= lifespan) || condition == ComponentCondition.damaged) {
      return scrapValue.toInt();
    }
    
    return 0;
  }

  void updateCondition(ComponentCondition partCondition) {
    condition = partCondition;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  ComponentModel engine = ComponentModel(componentPercent: 18, kerbWeight: 695, rate: 17, lifespan: 13, age: 2021);
  engine.updateCondition(ComponentCondition.good);
  final price = engine.calculatePrice();
  final price2 = engine.calculatePrice();
  print('price1 :$price');
  print('price2 : $price2');
}
```

And **now** you get a glaring compiler error saying:

> Error: The setter 'age' isn't defined for the class 'ComponentModel'.
>
> - 'ComponentModel' is from 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
>   age = DateTime.now().year - age;
>   ^^^
>   Error: Compilation failed.

This is **great**. The compiler just caught your error. You accidentially reassigned the `age` variable, instead of using a local variable, lets say something called "years". Maybe you should rename `this.age` to `this.ModelMakeYear` then your `age` local variable would be perfect.

So with this changes, your code *should* look like this:

```
enum ComponentCondition { missing, damaged, good }

class ComponentModel {
  String? name;
  ComponentCondition condition = ComponentCondition.good;

  final double rate;
  final double componentPercent;
  final double kerbWeight;
  final int lifespan;
  final int modelMakeYear;
  
  ComponentModel(
      {this.name,
      required this.rate,
      required this.lifespan,
      required this.kerbWeight,
      required this.componentPercent,
      required this.modelMakeYear });

  int calculatePrice() {
    final weight = (componentPercent * kerbWeight) / 100;
    final double scrapValue = weight * rate;
    final i = lifespan ~/ 3;
    
    final age = DateTime.now().year - modelMakeYear;

    if ((condition == ComponentCondition.good || condition == ComponentCondition.damaged) && i == 0) {
      return scrapValue.toInt();
    }
    
    if (condition == ComponentCondition.good && age < lifespan) {
      if (age >= 0 && age <= i) {
        print('bestconditionPrice');
        return (scrapValue * 3).toInt();
      } 
      
      if (age > i && age <= i * 2) {
        return (scrapValue * 2).toInt();
      } 
      
      if (age > i * 2 && age < lifespan) {
        return (scrapValue * 1.5).toInt();
      }
    } 
    
    if ((age >= lifespan) || condition == ComponentCondition.damaged) {
      return scrapValue.toInt();
    }
    
    return 0;
  }

  void updateCondition(ComponentCondition partCondition) {
    condition = partCondition;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final engine = ComponentModel(componentPercent: 18, kerbWeight: 695, rate: 17, lifespan: 13, modelMakeYear: 2021);
  engine.updateCondition(ComponentCondition.good);
  final price = engine.calculatePrice();
  final price2 = engine.calculatePrice();
  print('price1 :$price');
  print('price2 : $price2');
}
```

Works like a charm:

> bestconditionPrice
> bestconditionPrice
> price1 :6380
> price2 : 6380

The important part here is not the fish, but the fishing method: keep to all the best practices and *let your compiler do the heavy lifting*. It's a great tool, **use it**.

Comment: this answer is so helpful to me in many ways i was making the whole project so messy and lot of boilerplate codes were there but this gives me the idea to improve my code and optimise it thanks alot sir .

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the *age* variable in the class. So, the second calculation will be based on a different age and hence the disparity.

**Create a local age variable in the calculatePrice() function and perform calculations based on that for consistency**.

Comment: thankyou for answering I was stuck on this silly operation for hours thanks again :)

Comment: Happy to help :)